# Using an async task to download xml into String[]

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

So I'm trying to get an AsyncTask to go out and grab three different XML files. The issue is, I don't know how to then bring them back out of the AsyncTask

There is the GetXML Class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class GetXML extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String[]> {
@Override
protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String[] retreiver = new String[3];

    try {
        retreiver = getXMLs();
        return retreiver;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for(int i=0;i<retreiver.length;i++){
        retreiver[i]="<object_list><object><title>ERROR</title></object></object_list>";
    }
    return retreiver;
}


 private static String[] getXMLs() throws Exception {
        String[] urls = new String[3];

        urls[0] = "http://www.parkland.hostoi.com/XML_Files/indoor.xml";
        urls[1] = "http://www.parkland.hostoi.com/XML_Files/outdoor.xml";
        urls[2] = "http://www.parkland.hostoi.com/XML_Files/events.xml";

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        URLConnection uc = null;

        int i = 0;

        for(i=0;i<urls.length;i++){

            try {
                URL url = new URL(urls[i]);
                uc = url.openConnection();
                uc.connect();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                int read;
                char[] chars = new char[1024];
                while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1)
                    buffer.append(chars, 0, read);

                urls[i]= buffer.toString();
                } 
                finally {
                    if (reader != null)
                        reader.close();
                }
        }
        return urls;
 }
```

And then... what's next? Currently I have this bit on my Main Activity and I know it is the part causing the problems:

```
String[] xmls = new String[3];

    GetXML taskA = new GetXML();
    try {
        xmls = taskA.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But all this does is causes a crash or a timeout or something.... No errors are showing up in LogCat.

I just don't know. This is my first android project, and it is killing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
String[] xmls = new String[3];

    GetXML taskA = new GetXML();
    try {
        xmls = taskA.execute().get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Task not execute because you never executed,

Need to call

```
 taskA .execute();
```

Refer Below:

In main Activity:

```
GetXML taskA = new GetXML();
taskA.execute();
```

Your AsyncTask is:

```
public class GetXML extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String[]> {
        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String[] retreiver = new String[3];

            try {
                retreiver = getXMLs();
                return retreiver;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for(int i=0;i<retreiver.length;i++){
                retreiver[i]="<object_list><object><title>ERROR</title></object></object_list>";
            }
            return retreiver;
        }


        private String[] getXMLs() throws Exception {
            String[] urls = new String[3];

            urls[0] = "http://www.parkland.hostoi.com/XML_Files/indoor.xml";
            urls[1] = "http://www.parkland.hostoi.com/XML_Files/outdoor.xml";
            urls[2] = "http://www.parkland.hostoi.com/XML_Files/events.xml";

            BufferedReader reader = null;
            URLConnection uc = null;

            int i = 0;

            for(i=0;i<urls.length;i++){

                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urls[i]);
                    uc = url.openConnection();
                    uc.connect();
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                    int read;
                    char[] chars = new char[1024];
                    while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1)
                        buffer.append(chars, 0, read);

                    urls[i]= buffer.toString();
                } 
                finally {
                    if (reader != null)
                        reader.close();
                }
            }
            return urls;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            String[] xmls = result;
        }
    }
```

Result is populated in **onPostExecute**

Require Permission in manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: I had the manifest changed, but thank you for posting and leaving best practices on there.

Answer (score 0):

A nice example can be found in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

You need to call the `execute()` method on your task, not `get()`.

I'd also recommend at least implementing the `onPostExecute()` method as well in your `AsyncTask`.